# What is the equivalent of the Bootstrap 3 'btn-default' class in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

There was a nice button created by `btn-default` in Bootstrap 3.

```
<a class="btn btn-default">link</a>
```

Is there an equivalent in Bootstrap 4?

Comment: add this css to your stylesheet file .btn-default {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.btn-default:focus {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-color: #8c8c8c;
}
.btn-default:hover {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-color: #adadad;
}
.btn-default:active {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-color: #adadad;
}

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `btn-outline-secondary` class and `btn-outline-light` class in Bootstrap 4 are the 2 closest alternatives to what used to be `btn-default` in Bootstrap 3. (there's no exact equivalent in Bootstrap 4)

Here's a code snippet with live preview (notice the difference between a `button` and an `a` tag):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container m-3">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary">outline-secondary link</a>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">outline-secondary 'button'</button>
    <br><br>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-light">outline-light link</a>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">outline-light 'button'</button>
</div>
```

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#outline-buttons